# SpeechRecognizerUI in WP8 leading to high crash count?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have been working on a note taking app and I had included SpeechRecognizerUI so the user can take notes directly from speech. After putting this app up on store, I noticed a really high crash count. I've got several complaints from user too, saying that the app is crashing randomly. I tried it alot, but it didn't crash for me. So I exported the stack traces from the Dev Center website.

All the crashes have something to do with the SpeechRecognizerUI.. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Here's the code, i've used in the page:-

```
SpeechRecognizerUI recoWithUI;  //Speech to text
SpeechSynthesizer synth;    //Text to speech

public NoteView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    recoWithUI = new SpeechRecognizerUI();
    synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();
    recoWithUI.Recognizer.AudioProblemOccurred += Recognizer_AudioProblemOccurred;
}

private async void RecordButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SpeechRecognitionUIResult recoResult = await recoWithUI.RecognizeWithUIAsync();

        if (NoteBox.Text == "")
            NoteBox.Text = recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;
        else
            NoteBox.Text = NoteBox.Text + " " + recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text;
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}

async void Recognizer_AudioProblemOccurred(SpeechRecognizer sender, SpeechAudioProblemOccurredEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.NoSignal)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("I can't hear you");

    else if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooFast)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("That's too fast");

    else if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooLoud)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("That's too loud.");

    else if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooNoisy)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("There's too much noise");

    else if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooQuiet)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("Try speaking louder");

    else if (args.Problem == SpeechRecognitionAudioProblem.TooSlow)
        await synth.SpeakTextAsync("Try speaking faster");
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what causes the exception. I can only advise to put SpeechRecognizerUI into using directive.

Comment: It's there in the using directive. If it was not, the program wouldn't even compile. I don't see what's causing the error...And I've reached over 250 crashes in 5 days.

Comment: What i meant is `using (var speechRecognizer = new SpeechRecognizerUI()) {}` in `RecordButton_Click` method so the new object gets created and disposed each time user clicks the button.

Comment: Oh. Sorry for misunderstanding. I'll try that.. Thank you. The crashes seems to take place immediately when navigated to this page. Which means the initialization of the SpeechRecognizerUI object in the page's constructor might be causing the crash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this on before using recoResult.RecognitionResult.Text.

```
if (recoResult.RecognitionResult != null)
{
    //...
}
```